# UITableViewHeaderFooterView: Unable to change background color

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to change the background color of UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Although the view is appearing, the background color remains the default color. I'm getting a log from xcode saying:

> Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been
> deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead.

However, none of the following options work:

```
myTableViewHeaderFooterView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myTableViewHeaderFooterView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myTableViewHeaderFooterView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

I've also tried changing the background color of the view in the xib file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: in iOS 13, use contentView.backgroundColor worked for me. I think Apple updated this

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You should either use `myTableViewHeaderFooterView.tintColor`, or assign a custom background view to `myTableViewHeaderFooterView.backgroundView`.

Comment: myTableViewHeaderFooterView.tintColor works perfectly. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Don't know why, but for me `tintColor` not working on iOS7. 
I could change color only by assign custom view:
`myTableViewHeaderFooterView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];`

Comment: TintColor is not background color!!

Comment: Overriding `.tintColor` works if your `view` `background` is set to `Default` color instead of `System Background Default` color. But should not be using it as it is supposed to be tint color, not background color.

Answer (score 221):

## iOS 8, 9, 10, 11...

The only way to set any color (with any alpha) is to use `backgroundView`:

**Swift**

```swift
self.backgroundView = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
```

**Obj-C**

```m
self.backgroundView = ({
    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.5 alpha:0.5];
    view;
    });
```

---

**Responses to Comments**

- None of these other options reliably work *(despite the comments below)*

  ```swift
  // self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  // self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  // self.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  ```
- the `backgroundView` is resized automatically. *(No need to add constraints)*
- Control alpha with `UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)` or `backgroundView.alpha = 0.5`.
  *(of course, any color will do)*
- When using *XIB*, make root view a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and associate the `backgroundView` programmatically:

  *Register with:*

  ```swift
  tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "View", bundle: nil),
                     forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "header")
  ```

  *Load with:*

  ```swift
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      if let header =
          tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header") {
          let backgroundView = UIView(frame: header.bounds)
          backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
          header.backgroundView = backgroundView
          return header
      }
      return nil
  }
  ```

---

[image: Demo]

[↻ replay animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dvo5.gif)

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-15604900) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-15604900).

Comment: contentView doesnt exist that's why. tintcolor is to tint the view not its background. and backgroundcolor is deprecated. 

Thus your way is the way to make it to work.
Btw nice code syntax

Comment: @JoãoNunes, with C# / Xamarin the syntax is even neater: `view.BackgroundView = new UIView(view.Bounds) { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };`

Comment: In Xcode 6.1.1, you get a run-time console warning: `Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead.`

Comment: With Xcode6.2 beta5, I still got same warning. My creation method of UITableViewHeaderFooterView is based on loading xib which is similar to  Apple sample code, TVAnimationsGestures. However, TVAnimationGestures with Xcode6.2b5 does not generate any warning message. Apple code does not have 'background' string at all. Of course, uitableVuewHeaderFooterview.contentView is nil in TVAnimationsGestures. I don't understand why this happen.

Comment: ultraperfect, thank you so much for the one correct answer! Was fighting with that for a week or so! Even compiled under iOS7 does not work on iOS8 in old manner

Comment: Setting self.contentView.backgroundColor works just fine for me in iOS 8.1.3, 8.2 and 8.3 (for both solid colours and those with alpha)

Comment: With Better Obj-C syntax : `self.backgroundView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds]; self.backgroundView .backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: For people who still get the warning: make sure the UITableViewHeaderFooterView doesn't have a backgroundColor set in IB.

Comment: Wouldn't show for me; the backgroundView still had a rect of zero. I had to initialize the backgroundView with `backgroundView = UIView()` and then put `backgroundView!.frame = bounds` within my `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Excellent  answer！UITableViewHeaderFooterView`s backgroundView default is nil,  contentView is also nil, when I custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView with XIB file , why is that?

Comment: @BeyondChao: [Github](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-15604900) demo uses a **XIB**. Compare your code against that working project.

Comment: How can i keep this black background view as semi transparent and also don't have the cells visible behind it when i scroll at up (as displayed in your image.)

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani I believe the [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-15604900) demo does exactly what you are asking. Check `override func tableView` in `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Nope it doesn't. When i scroll the cells, i can see them behind the section header as section header has alpha 0.5

What i want is when i scroll the cells it goes up but doesn't show behind the section header

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani: please ask a new StackOverflow question

Answer (score 26):

In iOS 7 `contentView.backgroundColor` worked for me, `tintColor` did not.

```
   headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Though `clearColor` did not work for me, the solution I found is to set  `backgroundView` property to transparent image. Maybe it will help someone:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1, 1), NO, 0.0);
UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

headerView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:blank];
```

Comment: I think this is a better approach than @SwiftArchitect 's answer (Although it worked). The fact you don't have to add a new UIView makes it way better. Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you set the backgroundColor of the `contentView` for your `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`:

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Then it will work.

Comment: iOS >=10 only!. For iOS <10 use: backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

Answer (score 17):

For me I tried everything stated above but still was getting the warning 
"Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead." then I tried this:
within the xib file the background color for header view was selected to clear color instead of default once I changed it to default the warning went away. 
[image: was this]

[image: Changed to this]

Answer (score 12):

For solid background colors, setting the `contentView.backgroundColor` should be enough:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = .red // Works!
    }
}
```

For colors with transparency, including `.clear` color, this no longer works:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear // Does not work 
    }
}
```

For a full transparent section header, set the `backgroundView` property to an empty view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        headerView.backgroundView = UIView() // Works!
    }
}
```

However, beware of possible side effects. Unless the table view is set to "Grouped", section headers will snap at the top when scrolling down. If the section headers are transparent, the cell content will be seen through, which might not look great.

Here, section headers have transparent background:

[image]

To prevent this, it is better to set the background of the section header to a solid color (or gradient) matching the background of your table view or view controller.

Here, section headers have a fully opaque gradient background:

[image]

Comment: Genius! Defining an empty UIView for backgroundView totally solved the issue for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For a clear color, I use

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundView = [UIView new];
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

It seems fine to me.

Comment: Setting `backgroundView = UIView()` and then `backgroundColor = .clear` was the only working solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

[image]In interface builder pull up your .xib, on the top element, in attribute inspector set the background color to default. Then go to the Content View and set the background color there (reference to https://github.com/jiecao-fm/SwiftTheme/issues/24).

Answer (score 4):

On **iOS9** `headerView.backgroundView.backgroundColor` worked for me:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    TableViewHeader *headerView = (TableViewHeader *)[super tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section];
    headerView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

On **iOS8** I was using `headerView.contentView.backgroundColor` without problems, but now with iOS 9, I was getting a weird issue that made the background color not fill the whole space of the cell. So I tried just `headerView.backgroundColor` and I got the same error from the OP.

> Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been
>   deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead.

So now everything works great and without warnings by using `headerView.backgroundView.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 4):

If you are [customising a section header cell with Storyboard/Nib](http://samwize.com/2015/11/06/guide-to-customizing-uitableview-section-header-footer/), then make sure the background color is **default** for the "Table Section Header" view.

And if you subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, and using nib, then what you have to do is to create a `IBOutlet` for the content view, and name it eg. `containerView`. This is not to be confused with `contentView`, which is parent of this container view.

With that setup, you change the background color of `containerView` instead.

Answer (score 4):

if you created a custom subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` with `xib` file then you should override `setBackgroundColor`. Keep it empty.

```
-(void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor {

}
```

And this will solve your problem.

Comment: This is correct answer for me. Althought I don't set any background color in my HeaderFooterView but the warning message keeps come out in my console log. So annoying!

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the appearanceWhenContainedIn chain, and it worked for me.

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], [UITableView class], nil] 
         setBackgroundColor: [UIColor.grayColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe because the backgroundView doesn't exist

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect){
    // Drawing code
    let view = UIView()
    view.frame = rect
    self.backgroundView = view
    self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColorHere
}
```

that work for me.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 12, Swift 5. If you are willing (or trying!) to use an appearance proxy, the following solution works:

1. Subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView and expose your own appearance proxy setting.

```
final class MySectionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    @objc dynamic var forceBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get { return self.contentView.backgroundColor }
        set(color) {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = color
            // if your color is not opaque, adjust backgroundView as well
            self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```

2. Set the appearance proxy at your desired granularity.

```
MySectionHeaderView.appearance().forceBackgroundColor = .red
```

or

```
MySectionHeaderView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyOtherClass.self]).forceBackgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about difficulties.

Add to your project `UITableViewHeaderFooterView+BGUpdate.swift` with code below:

```
extension UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    open override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return self.backgroundColor
        }
        set {
            let bgView = UIView()
            bgView.backgroundColor = newValue
            backgroundView = bgView
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage** is simple as you expected before:

```
headerView.backgroundColor = .red
```

**Usage examples**:

1) In delegate's `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = tv.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "MyHeaderView")
    headerView.backgroundColor = .red // <- here
    return headerView
}
```

or

2) In your custom header view class:

```
class MyHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundColor = .red // <- here
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok... your way is better. :) Thanks

Comment: This solution causes a recursive loop on iOS 12.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in initializing of your **UITableViewHeaderFooterView** subclass:

```
let bgView = UIView()
bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
backgroundView = bgView
backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary in the answer for why this is the correct answer.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Now since iOS 14 we've got UIBackgroundConfiguration for UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

To change the background color I'm doing the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let headerView = view as? LeftMenuSectionHeader {
        if var backgroundConfig = headerView.backgroundConfiguration {
            backgroundConfig.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            headerView.backgroundConfiguration = backgroundConfig
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## XCode 15, iOS 13.0+

I had a custom table view header with a simple layout: a rounded subview, and a transparent background, in a `Plain Style` table. Everything works fine when I initialize the header view.

[image]

However, an issue occurs when scrolling the table and making the header view stick on top. There is a background even though I didn't set anything. Debug UI showing that it's kind of a `_UIVisualEffectBackdropView`.

[image]

I've tried these, and none of them work.

```
contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
backgroundView.backgroundColor = .clear
tintColor = .clear
```

---

**Fortunately, creating a new empty view and setting it to `header.backgroundView` when dequeuing the reuseable `viewForHeaderInSection` actually does the trick. One of the most weird things ever.**

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView...
    let bg = UIView()
    bg.backgroundColor = .clear
    header.backgroundView = bg
    ...
    return header
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the BackgroundView with clear color works fine for visible headers.
If the table is scrolled to show  headers at bottom ,this solution fails.

P.S.My table consists only of headers without any cells.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {
    var headerView: TableViewHeader = super.tableView(tableView, viewForHeaderInSection: section) as! TableViewHeader
    headerView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create UIView and set background color, then set it to self.backgroundView.

```
- (void)setupBackgroundColor:(UIColor *) color {
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    bgView.backgroundColor = color;
    self.backgroundView = bgView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel compelled to share my experience. 
I had this piece of code that worked fine with iOS 10 and iOS 11 `headerView?.contentView.backgroundColor = .lightGray`

Then I all of a sudden decided to to deploy the app for iOS 9 as there are some devices (iPad mini some older generation doesn't update to any OS beyond 9) - The only solution that worked for all iOS 9, 10 and 11 was to define a base view for the header that then contains all other header subviews, wire it up from storyboard and set the `backgroundColor` of that base view.

You will want to be mindful when wiring the outlet not to call it: `backgroundView` as there is already a property with that name in some `superclass`. I called mine `containingView`

Also when wiring the outlet control click on the view in `Document Outline` to make sure it's not wired up to `file owner`