# Can't change Background color of uitableviewheaderfooterview in IOS 7.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

There are a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604900/ios-uitableviewheaderfooterview-unable-to-change-background-color) of solutions suggested here in stackoverflow for the pre-iOS 7.0 and even ios 7.0. But none is working for me.

It seems most people have trouble setting the background colour to transparent. In my case I would like to get rid of the transparent colour, so that "Sunday 4th" gets a solid background and while scrolling down the time of the day doesn't interfere with the header as in the screenshot.

[image]

I have tried to set the tint colour and contentview without any luck:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    FTDayHeaderView *header = [[self recordTableView] dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"FTDayHeaderView"];
    //[header setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; Didn't work either
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return header;
}
```

This is `FTDayHeaderView`'s settings in the IB:

[image]

I deactivated `opaque` without any effect.

**UPDATE**:
As requested.

```
#import "FTDayHeaderView.h"

@implementation FTDayHeaderView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why are you downvoting without leaving any comment? I have done research and it didnt work for me. Try to be productive!!!

Comment: Is FTDayHeaderView a subclass of uiview right? So instead of header.contentView.backgroundColor you can set header.backgroundColor to blackColor. Also please share FTDayHeaderView's .m file content.

Comment: `FTDayHeaderView` is a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. I tried your trick without any joy. `[header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];` See updated question for more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *sv = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"SomeViewId"];
    sv.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 48.0)];
    sv.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    return sv;
}
```

I noticed, that the backgroundView was nil and created a view just for the background color. (You probably need to change the dimensions of the view... 48 was the height of my header view.)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it solves your problem, but it solved mine. Try to set the color in `willDisplayHeaderView` and adjust it to your code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]) {
        ((UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view).backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The table view sets state-based properties on its cells and header views (including `selected` and `backgroundColor`).  This method gives the delegate a chance to override the properties that the table view decided on.  Similarly, background colors for cells can be overridden in `willDisplayCell…`.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem lies in something else all way along. `header.backgroundView` is nil as Rainer mentioned.