# Changing the background color of UITableViewHeaderFooterView is not supported. Use the background view configuration instead

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I use xib to custom headerView and set default background color to this headerView, and I always get this warning. How to fix it? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

these property are not work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITableViewHeaderFooterView: Unable to change background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604900/uitableviewheaderfooterview-unable-to-change-background-color)

Comment: I already try and not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure, what did you mean by I already tried, clearly from the code snippet you posted you havent, You can either do this tableView delegate or in `awakeFromNib` of your headerView itself

```
guard let header =
        detailTableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "DetailListHeaderView") as? DetailListHeaderView else { fatalError("could not create headerView") }
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: header.bounds)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        header.backgroundView = backgroundView
        //other codes of yours
        return header
```

Comment: Thanks, But I already try this and not work and it show me the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting the background color property in IB to default solves the issue with the warning. However my top level item is view and yours is cell, which may have different default color, that causes the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the color of `contentView` e.g.

```
class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.txtLabel.textColor = .white
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    func bind(text: String) {
        self.txtLabel.text = text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this delegate method, with success ~! cut-n-paste coder, here we go ~!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id maybe = view;
    if ([maybe isKindOfClass:UITableViewHeaderFooterView.class]) {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = maybe;
        header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine...

1. Change your FooterView (Xib) content view color to Default
2. Change Inside FooterView (Xib) view color to Default
3. FooterView (Xib) Inside any button, you can set the background color otherwise, you can set the background color at the code level.